# Selecting a particular tag on hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple tags inside my `<div>`.

```
<div>
    <path class="link" d="somedata">
          <node>a</node>
    </path>

    <path class="link" d="somedata">
          <node>g</node>
    </path>

    <path class="link" d="somedata">
          <node>k</node>
    </path>
</div>
```

Assume that the output of a html is a connected node. Now I’m unable to select that particular path and node in jQuery and fetch the data present between the node tags.

Comment: share the rendered html and relevant js code.

Comment: It is sankey.js from d3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("node").hover(function(){
  var myVar = $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: For some reason, if i use selector as "path" then I'm able to see "<node>a</node>", but when I use the selector "node" nothing is visible.

Comment: Use `path` instead. Then try `var myVar = $(this).find("node").html();`

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$("path").mouseenter(function () {
    var myData  = $(this).text();
    alert(myData )
});
```

**OR**

```
$("node").mouseenter(function () {
    var myData  = $(this).text();
    alert(myData )
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO using path as selector](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/7gjcL0uq/2/)

[Fiddle DEMO using node as selector](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/7gjcL0uq/3/)

Comment: For some reason, if i use selector as "path" then I'm able to see "<node>a</node>", but when I use the selector "node" nothing is visible.

Comment: I have added demo using both the selectors.. please verify